# Prime factor at the highest power

Tags: python

I have to find the prime factor at the highest power.

I already found the prime factors and their powers but I don't know how to print the prime factor which has the highest power.

```py
d = 2
p = 0
while(n):
    p = 0
    while(n%d==0):
        p+=1
        n=n//d
    if(p):
        print("{0}^{1}".format(d,p))
    d+=1
```

For n = 1620, it should show 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code, saving prime factors, and fixing your infinite loop, just use a `max` call:

```
d = 2
p = 0
n = 1620
prime_factors = []
while(d < n):
    p = 0
    while(n % d == 0):
        p += 1
        n = n // d
    if(p):
        prime_factors.append((d, p))
    d += 1
# Tell max to use the second element (i.e. p) to find the max element
print(max(prime_factors, key=lambda x: x[1])) # (3 , 4)
# or
print("Largest power prime is {0[0]} with a power of {1[1]}".format(max(prime_factors, key=lambda x: x[1])) # Largest power prime is 3 with a power of 4.
```

There is probably a faster solution than yours (especially since yours doesn't short circuit at all) but I figured I would answer using your code so you can see what I did easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the list of divisors and count them with [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.Counter):

```
from math import sqrt
from collections import Counter

a = 1620
temp = a
divisors = []

# The largest divisor is not more than sqrt(a)
for i in range(2, int(sqrt(a)) + 1):
    # Divide while able
    while temp % i == 0:
        temp = temp // i
        divisors.append(i)
    # Found all divisors
    if temp == 1:
        break
# Print the most common divisor
print(Counter(divisors).most_common(1)[0])
```

It will print:

> `(3, 4)`

`3` is the most common divisor, `4` is its count. So if you want only the divisor, you can write this line:

`print(Counter(divisors).most_common(1)[0][0])`

instead of the last.